# Issue editing nodes on a PostGIS table via QGIS

Tags: postgresql, editing, qgis-2, postgis-2.0, nodes

I launch a PostGIS table via QGIS DB Manager tool [PostgreSQL 9.4.17 - PostGIS 2.1.8 - QGIS 2.18.19]. The table geometry is `MultiPolygon`. I can toggle both `Toggle editing` and `Node tool` buttons. When I click on map canvas in order to move nodes, I get the following message:

[image]

And the Log Messages Panel shows:

[image]

I can update attributes values and move features.

**The issue seems to be on editing nodes only.**

--

After having read several posts about editing a PostGIS table from QGIS, I've tried the followings without success:

- Connection parameters to DB using postgres default user or other user
- PostGIS table has both a primary key and an index on the geometry column
- Function `ST_IsValid()` returns only TRUE values (no invalid geometries)
- I can't connect directly via the "Add PostGIS layers" button's dialog for the DB is too big (over 50 schemas) and displaying the content is very long... Thus I use DB Manager instead.
- Settings > Options > Digitizing: tried different tolerance values both in map units and pixels. Also tried to set "To vertex" or "To vertex and segments".
- Settings > Snapping options: same tests.

What could I be missing?

Comment: The error is "Operation on mixed SRID geometries". Does your project use the same CRS than your table in PostGIS?

Comment: Yes, both tables and project are `SRID:3947` (tried with both on the fly CRS transformation on / off -> same issue). By the way, how can you see that the issue is a mixed SRID one?

Comment: By reading the error message that you attached.

Comment: OK, missed this message... Anyway, the message systematically prompted when trying to edit nodes is the other one: `Current transaction is aborted...`

Comment: It just tells that transaction was aborted but what is interesting is why it was aborted. Perhaps QGIS tries to send the edited geometries without SRID or with a wrong SRID. If you can make PostGIS to log the SQL statements and see what happens.

Comment: What is strange is that I can move features and the PostGIS table is updated correctly without any error message... The mixed SRID should also be a problem, then.

Comment: Consider to send mail to QGIS users mailing list and ask if that is some known bug.

Comment: Have you already checked each geometry? Try something like: `select distinct st_srid(the_geom) from schema.table;`. Does it only returns `3947`?

Comment: Yes I did ! Only `3947`returned...